# Action Listener to update the view of data between two classes

Tags: java, swing

I have a class A Frame, class B TextArea1, class C TextAre2, Class D Data.

Frame is where I initiate 2 textAreas & Data.

Both Textares are able to modify the data that Frame pass to them & show the content.

I want to know how when TextArea1 changes the data and update its view. It will also update the view of TextAre2.

(it's like add action listener to other class from a class.)

What kind of action listener can make that happen ?

```
Add button to update.
Add timer to refresh.
```

But those two are not what I want.

Comment: To get notified when text area is changed use following statement: `textArea.getDocument().addDocumentListener(my_listener_implementation);`. For more information read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) article.

Comment: A arguably simply solution is to share the same `Document` between both `JTextArea`s.  This way, when one is updated, the other will automatically be update as well

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy It works 50% for me. I also need to add Action Listener when highlighting words in TextArea. Anyway to do it?

Comment: @MadProgrammer can you explain a little bit the way to do it?

Comment: You can use both. DocumentListener to update, another text area when one is chaged. And a button with ActionListener to provide highlighting.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Thank you a lot.

Comment: @TranQuyen Well [that's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005011/live-updating-one-jtextarea-from-another-jtextarea/33005428#33005428) and [that's another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33050209/trouble-passing-input-from-one-jtextarea-into-another-jtextarea/33091747#33091747)